# dplyr::case_when executing result of all conditions not just TRUE condition

Tags: r, dplyr

When using `dplyr::case_when` with function calls after the `~`, the code below runs both `func1` and `func2`. Is there a way to get it run only the function where the case evaluates to `TRUE` ? I may be missing something obvious.

Note, the `case_when` will only return the value of the case evaluating to `TRUE`.

```
# Global variables showing that both functions have been run.
v1 <- ""
v2 <- ""

func1 <- function(x) {
  v1 <<- 111
  paste0("Ran func1: ", x)
}

func2 <- function(x) {
  v2 <<- 222
  paste0("Ran func2: ", x)
}

# This case_when will cause both func1 and func2 to be run. It should
# only run "func1".
x <- 1
retval <-
  dplyr::case_when(
    x == 1 ~ func1("x == 1"),
    x == 2 ~ func2("x == 2"),
    TRUE ~ "No function has been run."
  )

### OUTPUT: both v1 and v2 have been modified.

> retval
[1] "Ran func1: x == 1"
> v1
[1] 111
> v2
[1] 222
```

The desired `dplyr::case_when` output would be the same as the following code

```
v1 <- ""
v2 <- ""
if(x == 1) {
  func1("x == 1")
} else if(x == 2) {
  func2("x == 2")
} else {
  TRUE ~ "No function has been run."
}

### OUTPUT: Only v1 was changed in this case.
## [1] "Ran func1: x == 1"
v1
## [1] 111
v2
## [1] ""
```

Comment: I think this might be the same issue: https://community.rstudio.com/t/case-when-executes-custom-function-although-condition-isnt-met/24730/5 It likely pertains to the fact that case_when executes all the code, and only selects later.

Comment: @dcsuka thanks, it is related. This is definitely something that could be unexpected for folks (i.e. don't replace `if/else if/else` with `dplyr::case_when` if the code block is a function).

Comment: For sure, this caught me by surprise. It wasn't the first time `case_when` has behaved unpredictably in my experience. Also, it is supposedly vectorized but it runs O(n^2) for large vectors.